# How to login using steam account on my android application

Tags: android, openid, steam, steam-web-api

I am new to work with steam web API. I already practiced some examples on API call and get responses. But I couldn't find out any way that could login to steam using my own android application. I just want to know are there any documents to refer on this case.

I kindly request experts to help me.

Answer (score 0):

[This link to the steam documentation](https://steamcommunity.com/dev?l=english) may help you, as it works for webapps aswell. Steam uses [Open ID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID) for this process.

> Steam can act as an OpenID provider. This allows your application to authenticate a user's SteamID without requiring them to enter their Steam username or password on your site (which would be a violation of the API Terms of Use.) Just download an OpenID library for your language and platform of choice and use http://steamcommunity.com/openid as the provider. The returned Claimed ID will contain the user's 64-bit SteamID. (...)